# Resizing grouped objects without type deformation?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, cs6, resize

I wonder if there's any way to have a group of objects, and resizing that group but letting the type be unaffected, where the resize simply adjusts the type bounding box but not the type style? What I'd expect is a setting allowing me to resize the group where the text simply wraps in the new bounding box.

Here are images showing what I mean:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. When you resize multiple objects it's *always* a transformation. There is no way to keep area text from transforming as well.

You simply can't do what you want.

<sub>In fact.... Adobe even broke this very thing in InDesign. What you want used to work in InDesign CS4, but Adobe broke it starting with InDesign CS5... and they don't appear to care that it's broken.</sub>

Comment: damn, just my luck... Ok Scott, thanks a lot for the info. I guess I'll just need to cmd + shift away the text object when resizing groups.

Comment: You can reset horizontal/vertical scale on text with cmd-shift-x but i think thats about it

Comment: You can select multiple Area Type objects and scale them all equally without distorting the contained characters, but as soon as add a Point Type object or any other object to the selection, it becomes a transformation as @Scott described.

Answer (score 6):

Sort of.

After you resize and the text gets munged, you can snap it back to normal by setting the Vertical Scale and Horizontal Scale to 100% (or, whatever it was before).

*(this is also what the <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> shortcut Tim Human mentions does).*

[image]

Or, if you don't want any change at all, set a `Paragraph Style` or a `Character Style` and then re-apply it clearing overrides after the transformation.

Clunky, but maybe better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend shapes with text in particular direction without deforming the type, In Illustrator, use Direct Selection Tool, select the anchors of the side of your shape and text box, then drag them in particular direction (shift will snap to vertical/horizontal/other directions) [image: Example]

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can do it just hit and hold `shift` then resize!